# How to get the cell clicked from a dataTable in a dynamic UI?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

Consider this example with two dataTables. One of them is generated dynamically but I do not know how to get cell-clicked events from it.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("out"),
  uiOutput("dynamic"),
  DTOutput("normal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dynamic <- renderUI(
    renderDT(mtcars,
             rownames = FALSE,
             selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell"),
             options   = list(dom  = "t"     , pageLength = 5))
  )

  output$normal <- renderDT(iris,
                            rownames = FALSE,
                            selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell"),
                            options   = list(dom  = "t"     , pageLength = 5))


  output$out <- renderText({
    paste("Normal",  paste(input$normal_cells_selected, collapse = ""), "\n",
          "Dynamic", paste(input$dynamic_cells_selected, collapse = "")     )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is the best way to do this but I have managed to get it to work with a few amendments. Let me know how you get on......

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("out"),
  uiOutput("dynamic"),
  DTOutput("normal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dynamic <- renderUI({
    output$aa <- renderDT(mtcars,
                          rownames = FALSE,
                          selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell"),
                          options   = list(dom  = "t"     , pageLength = 5))
    DTOutput("aa")
  })
  
  output$normal <- renderDT(iris,
                            rownames = FALSE,
                            selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell"),
                            options   = list(dom  = "t"     , pageLength = 5))
  
  
  output$out <- renderText({
    paste("Normal",  paste(input$normal_cells_selected, collapse = ""), "\n",
          "Dynamic", paste(input$aa_cells_selected, collapse = ""))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The key here was to create an id to access the table! Good game.